# char**& argument confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
void func(char**& arg1);

int main() {
  char* container[3] = { "First", "Second", "Third" };
  char** pCon = &container[0];

  func(pCon);            // This works
  func(&container[0]);   // no known conversion from char** to char**&
}
```

I am clearly missing something here. My logic says that these two should be the same thing.

Comment: What should be the same thing? AFAIK, `&` is only a reference when you a declaring a variable/object. Otherwise it means "address of"

Comment: You're passing an reference to a temporary to a function expecting an non-temporary lvalue-reference.

Comment: BTW, the relaxation of allowing string literals initializing `char*` pointers, is removed in C++11 (although compilers are likely to still accept it). That is, your initial definition should really be `char const* container[3] = { ... };`.

Comment: By the way, `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary, e.g., you cannot bind a temporary obtained from the address-of operator to a non-const reference.